# Getting "Gateway Timeout" error when using Zuul proxy server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, hystrix

I am developing spring boot microservices for my project. I am using Zuul as a proxy server. However when I route the api calls always I am getting `Gateway Timeout` or `Internal Server` errors. I am also use feign client to call external api. When I do that, always following response is thrown:

**response**

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-08-16T10:10:10.128+0000",
  "status": 504,
  "error": "Gateway Timeout",
  "message": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Hystrix Readed time out"
}
```

I use docker to rum my microservices. And when I see the logs of zuul proxy server it look as follows:

**stack trace**

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:173) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:86) [brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:118) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:221) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:410) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:167) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 70 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 172.19.0.10:8087 [/172.19.0.10] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
    ... 130 common frames omitted Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 172.19.0.10:8087 [/172.19.0.10] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at brave.httpclient.TracingMainExec.execute(TracingMainExec.java:55) ~[brave-instrumentation-httpclient-5.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at brave.httpclient.TracingProtocolExec.execute(TracingProtocolExec.java:41) ~[brave-instrumentation-httpclient-5.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    ... 132 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    ... 176 common frames omitted
```

I have also included the pom.xml and application.yml file of zuul proxy server.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.adl.dms.mobile.zuul-proxy-service</groupId>
    <artifactId>zuul-proxy-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>zuul-proxy-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <keycloak.version>5.0.0</keycloak.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> 
</project>
```

**application.yml**

```
    server:
      port: 8765

    eureka:
      client:
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://eureka-naming-server:8761/eureka/
      instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
        metadataMap:
          instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
        instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}

    zuul:
      prefix: /api
      sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
      ignore-security-headers: false
      routes:
        message-management-service:
          path: /message-management/**
          service-id: MESSAGE-MANAGEMENT-SERVICE
        user-management-service:
          path: /user-management/**
          service-id: USER-MANAGEMENT-SERVICE
      host:
        socket-timeout-millis: 60000
      ribbon:
        eager-load:
          enabled: true      

    spring:
      zipkin:
        base-url: http://zipkin-server:9411/
      sleuth:
        sampler:
          probability: 1

    hystrix:
      command:
        default:
          execution:
            isolation:
              thread:
                timeoutInMilliseconds:  11000
            timeout:
              enabled: false

    ribbon:
      ConnectTimeout: 10000
      ReadTimeout: 10000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  connection-timeout: 3000
  eureka:
    enabled: true
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  host:
    time-to-live: -1
    connect-timeout-millis: 5000
    max-per-route-connections: 10000
    max-total-connections: 5000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000
  semaphore:
    max-semaphores: 500
```

Setting this at Zuul Level will resolve the issue
Note: Please make sure the format is as per yml or properties what ever type is used